# zlib: Decompressed File Size?

Tags: zlib, compression

I'm using zlib to decompress a file. I want to verify that there is enough disk space to unzip the file. Do the zip format and zlib provide facilities to determine the decompressed size of its contents?

Answer (score 1):

If your file was compressed using the gzip format (RFC1952), then the last 4 bytes, the ISIZE field indicates the uncompressed file size mod 2^32. Therefore, provided that the original file was smaller than 4GB, you can determine its size by reading the last 4 bytes. Check the man pages for gunzip.

If ZLIB or raw Deflate format was used, you will have to decompress first to determine the uncompressed size.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple file structure for compressing:

`{`
`FileFormatHeader (optional) x bytes`
`OriginalSize (4 or 8 bytes)`
`CompressedSize (optional) (4 or 8 bytes)`
`HashSum (optional) (16 bytes or different number [depends on hash algorithm])`

`CompressedData`
`}`

Now you have all the information that you need for decompressing