# Decompress data in Span<byte> with Deflate algorithm

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-7.2

I have a code that parses a binary file. It uses `Span<byte>` to pass chunks of data among functions to avoid unnecessary memory allocations.

Simplified example:

```
class Reader {
    bool IsCompressed { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    function ReadOnlySpan<byte> ReadBlock() {
        ...
    }

    public function Read() {
        if (IsCompressed) {
            Data = ???
        } else {
             Data = ReadBlock.ToArray();
        }
}
```

I can decompress data with `Syste.IO.Compression.DeflateStream`, but this class accepts only `Stream` as the input, so I have to convert `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` to a stream and thus allocate memory for `byte[]`.

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer.ToArray())) {
    using(var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
        Data = ... read from deflateStream
    }
}
```

Is there any way to pass `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` to the `DeflateStream` without allocating unnecessary memory? Or is there any other library, that can decompress data directly from `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`?

I am using .NET Core 2.1.0-preview1-26103-03, but I can use any other version if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

As of January 2018, there isn't any build-in support for `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`, but as Stephen Toub pointed out on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26242#issuecomment-356465832) it can be solved with the `UnmanagedMemoryStream`

```
private unsafe byte[] Decompress(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer, int decompressedSize) {
    fixed (byte* pBuffer = &buffer[0]) {
        using (var stream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(pBuffer, buffer.Length)) {
            using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
                var data = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(decompressedSize);
                deflateStream.Read(data, 0, decompressedSize);

                return data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine the `decompressedSize`?

Comment: In my case I know the decompressed size, because the compressed block of data is part a more complex file format that stores decompressed size alongside the compressed data. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33444863/247656

Comment: for my understanding, you are returning rented array, how about the caller didn't return the array?

Comment: @shtse8 in the general case, it might be a problem, but as you can see my code snippet contains private function so I can guarantee the array is returned to the pool.

Comment: @LukasKabrt I suggest you should make a line here to remind people who want to take this answer, or it may lead to memory leakage as the rented array didn't return in potential.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if unmanaged code is needed, perhaps consider something like this:

```
using var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Resources.Data.zip");
if (resource is null)
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Data.Zip", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

using (ZipArchive archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(stream: resource))
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (string.Equals(entry.Name, "My.json", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            using var unZip = entry.Open();
            var bytes=new byte[(int)entry.CompressedLength].AsSpan();
            unZip.Read(bytes);                               
            var data= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
        }
    }
}
```

Performs ok and lowers the size of embedded resources considerably